# Typescript: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props' for imported interface

Tags: typescript

I am importing an interface into my Card component, and extending CardProps. A yarn build (Typescript 4.5.4) shows this error:

```
Type error: Type '{ children: Element[]; className: string; border: true; disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CardProps'.

> 79 |                 <Card/
```

My code is as follows

```
// types.ts
export interface BaseComponentProps {
    children?: ReactNode | undefined;
    className?: string;
    style?: Record<string, unknown>;
    onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
    onMouseOver?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
    onMouseLeave?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
    key?: number | string | null;
    'data-testid'?: string;
}

// card.tsx
import type { BaseComponentProps } from 'src/types';

interface CardProps extends BaseComponentProps {
  border?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}
export function Card({ border = false, disabled = false, className, children }: CardProps): JSX.Element { ... }
```

All Card children are JSX.Element types and I've exhausted many options suggested by our chatty 'AI friend'.

I can duplicate 'children' in CardProps and the error goes away, also if I move BaseComponentProps into Card.tsx it goes away. Should extending an interface containing optional properties via a type import affect this?

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox with the error ?

Comment: I can't reproduce in sandbox, still trying

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue before in react and it was cleared using given syntax you also can Try , may be helps to you

Thank you

```js
export const Card: FC<CardProps> = ({ border = false, disabled = false, className, children }:CardProps) => {return {.. goes here ...} }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the error.

Comment: i tried in sandbox but it's doesn't give any error. sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-23th2t

if you still facing error then update sandbox and send here. I will give my best to resolve your error.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to reproduce myself